# How to show whether a set is exhaustive.

Tags: probability

I know that for two sets to be mutually exclusive, $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$. If it turns out that $P(A\cup B) \neq P(A)+P(B)$, does this imply that they are exhaustive?

I am given that, $P(J)=\frac{7}{12}$, $P(K)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $P(J\cap K')=\frac{1}{4}$. How would I go about showing whether $J$ and $K$ are exhaustive or not?

Comment: For your first question:  You throw a fair die....$A=B$ is the event "you throw a $1$".

Comment: Drawing a Venn diagram, you can use the given info to calculate $P(J' \cap K')$. If this is zero, they are exhaustive. If not, they are not.

Comment: how do i go about using a Venn diagram..i know one circle would be event $J$ and the other event $K$ and the middle be $P(J\cup K)$..however figuring out the numbers in each circle and outside the diagram is troubling to me @MikeEarnest

Comment: You know that one of the regions has an area of $\frac14$. Use that, combined with the fact that that region adds up with another region to make $\frac7{12}$, to deduce the area of another region. And so on...

Comment: @MikeEarnest what region of the diagram would represent $J\cap K'$?